# Missing LanguageLocaleKey in SAML response?

Tags: saml, security-token

We (company XYZ) is a service providers and I am setting up XYZ as a custom app in SFDC (testing in SFDC Developers account).
I successfully configured SFDC as Identity Provider, and Company XYZ as service provider. I am able to get XYZ authenticated by SFDC and also query SFDC objects using REST API, configured that too.
All is good so far.
Now I am trying to get **User.LanguageLocaleKey** as part of the SAML Token, I looked at the custom attributes on Connected App. I see user details like first name, last name etc., but nothing related to language (LanguageLocaleKey). I am able to query User.LanguageLocaleKey using rest api.

How can I get **User.LanguageLocaleKey** as part of SAML token? Our requirement is, once user redirected to our site (XYZ), we make use of LanguageLocaleKey to switch XYZ site language (internationalization).

Answer (score 0):

A trigger on create/update events that will write the value of User.LanguageLocaleKey to a custom field on the User object. You can then map an attribute to this custom field in your SAML response.

Comment: I believe adding a custom field to user object make it available to configure Custom Attributes when setting up a Connected app. Unfortunately I am not a SFDC developer. I will have to approach my client (SFDC user) to setup that.